# Multiple Table Query with SUM and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, multiple-tables

I am struggling writing a (to me!) complex query which will calculate the total number of units sold of items, pulling data from two separate tables. I am using MySQL.

The first table is a simple 'order_contents' table (`sale_ord_contents` in my example) with item_id's and the quantity sold. Some items may be an Assembly, in which case their contents are stored in another table, `sale_ord_assembly_contents`, along with the quantity of each subcomponent. In my example here, the only 'Assembly' is the Fruit Basket. I have made a note that one of the Fruit Basket entries has a quantity sold of (2), meaning all of its contents should have their quantity multiplied by two.

[image]

My goal is to find the 20 most common items by their accumulative quantity sold between the two tables. The part I am struggling with the most is how to handle multiplying the values of subcomponents by their quantity of the parent in the `sale_ord_contents` table.

I have written this query which handles the `sale_ord_contents` calculation, but I am having trouble joining in the data from the `sale_ord_assembly_contents` table...

```
SELECT
   item_id, name, sku,
   SUM(quantity) AS purchases
FROM
   sale_ord_contents
GROUP BY
   item_id
ORDER BY purchases DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Am I going to be better off doing this in PHP, or is this feasible in MySQL? If so, could a SQL guru assist me in writing a query that provides the desired results? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my answer, please try again the following:

```
SELECT
    IF (soac.item_id IS NULL, soc.item_id, soac.item_id) as item_id,
    IF (soac.name IS NULL, soc.name, soac.name) as name,
    SUM(soc.quantity * COALESCE(soac.quantity, 1)) AS total_sold
FROM
    sale_ord_contents soc
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sale_ord_assembly_contents soac
           ON soac.order_item_id = soc.id
GROUP BY
    IF (soac.quantity IS NULL, soc.item_id, soac.item_id),
    IF (soac.name IS NULL, soc.name, soac.name)
ORDER BY total_sold DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Column names are good! However this query does not yield the desired results; it is seemingly not counting the rows in the assembly contents table, as the resulting total for 'Orange' is 26 (should be 32). Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it. According to provided screenshot with the content of sale_ord_contents table, looks like 26 is a correct result for 'Orange' (i.e. 1+10+10+5). Could you please explain how you've got 32 ?

Comment: No problem! The sale_ord_assembly_contents table provides the contents of items labeled as "assembly" in the sale_ord_contents table. There are a total of 3 "Fruit Baskets" assemblies in the sale_ord_contents table. Each Fruit Basket contains (2) Apples (as per the sale_ord_assembly_contents table), therefore the count should be: 1+10+10+5+(2*2)+(2*1) (the later two being the quantity of Apples in the fruit basket, multiplied by the number of Fruit Baskets purchased (2 on row 3, 1 on row 8)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I've got it. Updated my answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its feasible and the query execution time is also less as you have limit the number of rows returned. Please check in query optimizer in mysql workbench to get the query response time :). Writing too many for loops in php will degrade the page response time and exection time will be more. So its better to write high level application queries in your php code to get the better response time for your web pages :)

Comment: Thank you for your input! I am very familiar with the drawbacks of using loop-intensive code which is why I was trying to write this query. Unfortunately my SQL skills are a bit lacking in comparison to my coding ability, hence the question :) I am struggling particularly with the 'if item row is assembly then multiply quantity of all related rows in assembly_contents by the quantity of the assembly`

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving your problem is a left join. Essentially what this does is it matches up values between the table on the left and the table on the right side of the `left join`. If the table on the right doesn't have any values that match up correctly, `null` is inserted instead. Doing a left join between sale_ord_contents and sale_ord_assembly_contents will yield results like this:

> ```
> Sale_ord_contents_name | quantity | sale_ord_assembly_contents_name | quantity
> apple                  | 5        |    null                         |  null
> fruitbasket 1          | 1        |    apple                        |  3
> fruitbasket 1          | 1        |    orange                       |  1
> ```

These numbers don't match up with the example you provided, but you get the point. This is exactly what you will need to find the correct numbers.

The next keyword that is important is `coalesce`. What this does is it goes through the list of items that you have provided and returns the first value that is not null. So if I use coalesce(sale_ord_assembly_contents_name, sale_ord_contents_name), for the above example the null in the assembly table will be ignored and apple will be returned. Then, since the assembly name exists for the next two rows, apple and orange will be the value returned by the coalesce.

I believe the following query is what you will need:

```
SELECT
   coalesce(soa.item_id, so.item_id) as item_id,
   coalesce(soa.name, so.name) as name,
   so.sku,
   SUM(so.quantity * coalesce(soa.quantity, 1)) AS purchases
FROM
   sale_ord_contents so
   left join sale_ord_assembly_contents soa
   on so.id = soa.order_item_id
GROUP BY
   item_id, name, so.sku
ORDER BY purchases DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and helpful description, @Jenn! The results however, are a bit off. The query returns a total of 104 purchases for 'Orange' and 60 purchases for 'Apple'

Comment: @JohnHall it seems I had a few typos. I believe they have been corrected. test fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c80455/18